# object HTMLDivElement error displays on page

Tags: typescript, dom, calculator

currently I'm working on calculator in Typescript, and I got the one issue, when I click the button I want to add the number, everything is working well, but issue is displays `[object HTMLDivElement]` and when I click multiple times button it adds the text a number like that `[object HTMLDivElement]222222`

I'm using Classes to make calculator and here is my little code where I get this issue

```js
appendNumber(number) {
        if (number === '.' && this.currentOperandText.includes('.')) return;
        //Here is the code I convert them as string to add the numbers together
        this.currentOperandText = String(this.currentOperandText) + String(number);
    }
```

and after that I make Eventlistner function as `appendNumber` on buttons to display number

```js
const calculator = new Calculator(current, previous);
numbers.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.appendNumber(element.innerHTML);
        //updateDisplay is another Method to which displays the clicked numbers on page
        calculator.updateDisplay();
    });
});
```

*if you want to check how my calculator works here is link* **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/callmenikk/2L0tvsw8/8/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first call `appendNumber(number)`, `this.currentOperandText` is the HTMLDivElement object, which means running `this.currentOperandText.toString()` will return `[object HTMLDivElement]`. Add an if statement as below to check for this.

```
if (this.currentOperandText.toString() !== '[object HTMLDivElement]')
{
  this.currentOperandText = this.currentOperandText.toString() + number.toString()
} else {
  this.currentOperandText = number.toString()
}
```

Comment: @callmenikk - Happy to help. Good luck on your coding journey. Remember `console.log` is your friend. If ever something seems to be giving you incorrect information, `console.log` it to see what's going on.